# UIImageView's width setting failed

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I set a UIImageView's width to 0 in Size Inspector.and with the code

```
-viewDidLoad
{
  ...
  //smallTiao is the outlet of UIImageView
  NSLog(@"smallTiao 's width %f",self.smallTiao.frame.size.width);
}
```

Xcode log smallTiao 's width 0.000000
But actually the image view's width isn't 0 in iPad simulator.I don't know why.

**UPDATE**
The problem solved.I delete the image view.And I add a new one.Then everything works well.

Comment: You set 0 and getting 0.0000000 isn't both are same, (minusing int and float)?

Comment: Are you creating the image view from code or using Interface "Crappy" Builder?

Comment: @H2CO3 I create image view in Interface Builder.

Comment: why are you using 0 width imageview.?

Comment: @nimingzhe2008 And are you sure it's connected properly to the actual property of your class? If it isn't, then `self.smallTiao` is `nil`, and from that, any other message sent to it returns 0.

Comment: @V.J. Because when one button is touched,the image view's width will be set to normal value.

Comment: some where else you are changing the frame.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm sure smallTiao isn't nil.

Comment: @nimingzhe2008 Did you `NSLog()` it as well?

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes.if (!smallTiao) {
        NSLog(@"smallTiao is nill");
    }

Comment: @nimingzhe2008 Weird. What if you `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.smallTiao.frame));`?

Comment: @H2CO3 {{259, 378}, {0, 323}}

Comment: @nimingzhe2008 Yet it is displayed on screen and visible in its full width?

Comment: @H2CO3 it is displayed on screen but not full width

Comment: @nimingzhe2008 But I see you solved it, I'm glad it worked finally. Lesson: programming is done using *code* and not by drag'n'dropping stuff onto the screen.

Comment: @H2CO3 Do you mean I should use code to create image view?

Comment: @nimingzhe2008 I can't tell you what to do :) *Personally,* I find Interface Builder so full of bad concepts and counterintuitive features that in fact it's easier for me to create an UI from code.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sometimes I have the same feeling.Thank you very much.